# Why is `Selection.isCollapsed` always true in a shadow DOM?

Tags: selection, web-component, shadow-dom

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/isCollapsed) and [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/selection-range#selection-properties), `Selection.isCollapsed` should be `false` if there is any currently selected text. With regular DOM, this works as expected, but with shadow DOM, `isCollapsed` always seems to be `true`, even if some text is currently selected. Interestingly, calling `getSelection()` in shadow DOM does seem to correctly return the current selection—stuff like `anchorNode` and `anchorOffset` are correct. But `isCollapsed` is always `true`, even when it should be `false`.

Here's an example codesandbox ([editor](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-mayer-zqwv8?file=/src/index.js), [web view](https://zqwv8.csb.app/)), and here's a code example:

```js
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = "<h1>Hello DOM</h1>";

window.customElements.define(
  "example-component",
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      const mountPoint = document.createElement("div");
      this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
      mountPoint.innerHTML = `<h1>hello Shadow DOM</h1>`;
      this.shadowRoot?.appendChild(mountPoint);
    }
  }
);

document.addEventListener("selectionchange", () => {
  console.log("dom selectionchange");
  console.log(window.getSelection());
  console.log("shadow dom selectionchange");
  console.log(
    document.querySelector("example-component").shadowRoot.getSelection()
  );
});
```

I'm using Chrome 92.

It does seem there are several issues with the Selection API and shadow dom/web components, but as I said, it seems to *mostly* be working, just that this one property is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem is that `shadowRoot.getSelection()` is not a standard API, and is only supported in Chromium-based browsers. And `document.getSelection()` doesn't support selections that lie inside a shadow root.

There's work underway to expand the Selection APIs to support shadow DOM, and you can see a summary of the current proposal [in this comment](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/79#issuecomment-965900820). If this proposal reaches consensus, the `shadowRoot.getSelection()` API will likely be deprecated from Chrome, since the new `selection.getComposedRange()` API will supplant it.

In the meantime, the behavior in the OP here appears to be a bug in Chromium: the `isCollapsed` value is used from `document.getSelection()` even if the selection comes from `shadowRoot.getSelection()`. I filed a [bug for this](https://crbug.com/1271619). Given the work above to work on a replacement, I'm not sure it'll get too much attention, but maybe!

Comment: Many thanks. Including a link to the relevant caniuse here: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_shadowroot_getselection